# how to post variables between two php files

Tags: php, forms

my problem is sending variables between two php files
i know there is session for these stuff but i don't wanna use session for this... i want to have something as it POSTs in html forms..i used cURL like this between two files
ss.php

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost/dd.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Hello=World&Foo=Bar&Baz=Wombat");

curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

and there is second file called dd.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['Hello'];
?>
```

it works fine but the problem is it doesn't redirect to dd.php file... like it does in forms in html files
how can i get it redirected to the second file?

Comment: `header('Location: '.$newURL);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to redirect to the dd.php

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: it doesn't make any difference.. still it is ss.php in the address bar

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding how web requests work, so let's take a step back...

When a user goes from one page to another, the *server* isn't making this happen.  The *client* is.  The user's browser is displaying a page, then it makes a request for another page.  This is *also* true of redirects.  In the case of a redirect, the server is responding with the redirect address and the client is taking that information and making another request.

The order of steps is like this:

1. User visits Page 1.
2. User makes request for Page 2.
3. Page 2 responds with redirect to Page 3.
4. User makes request for Page 3.  (The browser does this automatically.)
5. Page 3 responds with content.

At no point does Page 2 *send anything* to Page 3.  So unless you persist the data somewhere that both pages can access (session, database, etc.) then you need the *user* to send the data.  In this particular scenario, that would have to be as query string values in the redirect.  (Since a redirect results in a GET request.)  Something like this:

```
header('Location: dd.php?Hello=World&Foo=Bar&Baz=Wombat');
```

This would redirect the user like any other redirect, and the URL simply contains the values you want the user to carry to the next page.

If it's data you don't want the user to see, or is a significant amount of data, then you'll want to fall back to some server-side persistence (session, database, etc.) instead of routing the data through the request itself.

---

Alternatively, you *could* make the cURL request as you do now and *then* perform the redirect.  But I *highly doubt* that's what you want, since that would be making *two* requests to the target page.  One made by the server to post the data, and another entirely separate one made by the client to navigate to the page.  And those requests would have nothing to do with one another and wouldn't share data.

Comment: so how is it possible to do what i want?
is it even possible?

Comment: @VahidAbdi: What specifically is it that you want to do?  If you specifically want to have the user make a POST request to another page then that won't happen with a redirect.  You'd have to render an actual page (albeit a visually empty one if you want) which contains a form and JavaScript to post that form to the target page.  That, however, seems a bit over-complicated and much less than ideal.  Is there a particular reason you can't accomplish this with query string values on the redirect or with persisted data server-side?

Comment: well first i appreciate that u answer
actually i am using SESSION to send variables between php files.. i was just asking if we can use POST for this or not.. as it seems the answer is not

Comment: @VahidAbdi: Well, it's not that you *can't*, it's that you can't in the specific way that you were trying.  Depending on how the UX flows from page to page, you may be able to do what you want by simply having the first page POST a form to the target page without involving a middle-man server-side step at all.  The context of the question doesn't really reveal why that can't be done, but I assume there's more to it than presented here.  The main point is that in order for a request to contain POST values, the user has to make a POST request somehow.

Comment: oh i understand.. i was trying to post a variable from a php file into another php file just for coding...